# Optimal way to recursively find files that match one or more patterns

Tags: bash, grep, find

I have to optimize a shell script, but after one week, i didn't succeed to optimize it enough.

I have to search recursively for .c .h and .cpp file in a directory, and check if word like this exist:
"float short unsigned continue for signed void default goto sizeof volatile do if static while"

```
words=$(echo $@ | sed 's/ /\\|/g')

files=$(find $dir -name '*.cpp' -o -name '*.c' -o -name '*.h' )

for file in  $files; do
(
        test=$(grep -woh "$words" "$file" | sort -u | awk '{print}' ORS=' ')
        if [ "$test" != "" ] ; then
          echo "$(realpath $file) contains : $test"
        fi
)&
done
wait
```

I have tried with xargs and -exec, but no result, i have to keep this result format:

> /usr/include/c++/6/bits/stl_set.h contains : default for if void

Maybe you can help me (to optimize it)..

EDIT: I have to keep one occurence of each word
YES: while, for, volatile... 
NOPE: while, for, for, volatile...

Comment: i tried this with `egrep` instead of `grep` and it worked. `grep -E` should work as well

Comment: It's working, but i have to optimize it more.. :/
It takes something like 1.5s and it has to be 0.6s -.-

Comment: if performance is that much of an issue, then maybe a shell script isn't the way to do it. did you try the provided answers?

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested in finding all files that have at least one match of any of your patterns, you can use [globstar](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Shopt-Builtin.html):

```
shopt -s globstar
oldIFS=$IFS; IFS='|'; patterns="$*"; IFS=$oldIFS  # make a | delimited string from arguments
grep -lwE "$patterns" **/*.c **/*.h **/*.cpp       # list files with matching patterns
```

---

> globstar
>
> If set, the pattern ‘**’ used in a filename expansion context
>   will match all files and zero or more directories and subdirectories.
>   If the pattern is followed by a ‘/’, only directories and
>   subdirectories match.

Comment: shopt not found ..

We haven't seen that, so i think, it isn't what we have to use :')
But thank you for you answer !

Comment: What version of bash are you using?

Comment: (School)
GNU bash, version 4.4.12(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approach that keeps your desired format while eliminating the use of find and bash looping:

```
words='float|short|unsigned|continue|for|signed|void|default|goto|sizeof|volatile|do|if|static|while'
grep  -rwoE --include '*.[ch]' --include '*.cpp' "$words" path | awk -F: '$1!=last{printf "%s%s: contains %s",r,$1,$2; last=$1; r=ORS; delete a; a[$2]} $1==last && !($2 in a){printf " %s",$2; a[$2]} END{print""}'
```

#### How it works

- `grep  -rwoE --include '*.[ch]' --include '*.cpp' "$words"` path

  This searches recursively through directories starting with `path` looking only in files whose names match the globs `*.[ch]` or `*.cpp`.
- `awk -F: '$1!=last{printf "%s%s: contains %s",r,$1,$2; last=$1; r=ORS; delete a; a[$2]} $1==last{printf " %s",$2} END{print""}'`

  This awk command reformats the output of `grep` to match your desired output.  The script uses a variable `last` and array `a`.  `last` keeps track of which file we are on and `a` contains the list of words seen so far.  In more detail:

  - `-F:`

    This tells awk to use `:` as the field separator. In this way, the first field is the file name and the second is the word that is found.  (limitation: file names that include `:` are not supported.)
  - '$1!=last{printf "%s%s: contains %s",r,$1,$2; last=$1; r=ORS; delete a; a[$2]}

    Every time that the file name, `$1`, does not match the variable `last`, we start the output for a new file.  Then, we update `last` to contain the name of this new file.  We then delete array `a` and then assign key `$2` to a new array `a`.
  - `$1==last && !($2 in a){printf " %s",$2; a[$2]}`

    If the current file name is the same as the previous and the current word has not been seen before, we print out the new word found.  We also add this word, `$2` as a key to array `a`.
  - `END{print""}`

    This prints out a final newline (record separator) character.

#### Multiline version of code

For those who prefer their code spread out over multiple lines:

```
grep  -rwoE \
    --include '*.[ch]' \
    --include '*.cpp' \
    "$words" path | 
    awk -F: '
        $1!=last{
            printf "%s%s: contains %s",r,$1,$2
            last=$1
            r=ORS
            delete a
            a[$2]
        }
        $1==last && !($2 in a){
            printf " %s",$2; a[$2]
        }
        END{
            print""
        }'
```

Comment: Wow ! It's almost the result, but how to keep only one occurence of each word ?

Comment: @HectoFR OK.  I just updated the code to keep display only one occurrence.

Comment: Uuu, it's working, but really to slow .. :/

(10.7s)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do most of this with a single `grep` command:

```
grep -Rw $dir --include \*.c --include \*.h --include \*.cpp -oe "$words"
```

This will put it in file:word format, so all that's left is to change it to produce the output that you want.

```
echo $output | sed 's/:/ /g' | awk '{print $1 " contains : " $2}'
```

Then you can add `| sort -u` to get only single occurrences for each word in each file.

---

```
#!/bin/bash

#dir=.
words=$(echo $@ | sed 's/ /\\|/g')

grep -Rw $dir --include \*.c --include \*.h --include \*.cpp -oe "$words" \
    | sort -u \
    | sed 's/:/ /g' \
    | awk '{print $1 " contains : " $2}'
```

Comment: I have already tried something like that but, unless I am mistaken, that will keep each occurence of each word, where i just want one by word

And it print one word by line, where i must have one line per file

Comment: Thx for your help, but

It prints one word by line, but i must have one line per file (file: for while...)

and it's a "little bit" slower than my version (19s)

Comment: Okay. I'd recommend adding that output specification into your OP then; that is not exactly obvious from the code itself. I'd continue to work on to try to make the output correct but as you say it's less optimized apparently so I'll abstain from further input.

Comment: Done,

Thanks for trying :)